# Copying files with component build process isn't working

Tags: javascript, node.js, component.io

I'm using [component](https://github.com/component) and [component build](https://github.com/component/builder2.js) to manage and build my frontend dependencies. I have a node script, taken from [the examples](https://github.com/component/builder2.js#example), that builds all my components. But it isn't copying my files. This is the offending part (full code included below):

```
build.files(tree)
  .use('files', build.plugins.copy())
  .use('fonts', build.plugins.copy())
  .use('images', build.plugins.copy())
  .end();
```

I think it's not working because there is no `fs.writeFileSync()` call anywhere in the example, but I'm not sure if it needs that. According to the examples it should copy the files listed in my component.json, which looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "component"
  "images": [
    "logo.jpg"
  ]
}
```

But it isn't copying my images to the build folder (I believe there aren't any mistakes in the component.jsons or the components themselves, I suspect it is something with the build code). This is the full script:

```
/**
 * =============================================================================
 * Builder (https://github.com/component/builder2.js)
 * =============================================================================
 */

var fs = require('fs');
var resolve = require('component-resolver');
var build = require('component-builder');
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');

var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2), {boolean: true}); // parse argument options
var src = process.cwd() + '/' + argv.src;
var dest = process.cwd() + '/' + argv.dest;
var components = process.cwd() + '/' + argv.components;
var buildname = argv.buildname;
var dev = argv.dev || false;

// resolve the dependency tree
resolve(src, {
  install: true, // install the remote components locally
  development: dev, // whether to include development components
  out: components // folder to install components to
}, function (err, tree) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // create 'dest' path
  mkdirp(dest, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });

  // build `.js` files from components' `.scripts` field
  build.scripts(tree)
    .use('scripts', build.plugins.js())
    .end(function (err, string) {
      if (err) throw err;
      fs.writeFileSync(dest + '/' + buildname + '.js', string);
    });

  // build `.css` files from components' `.styles` field
  build.styles(tree)
    .use('styles', build.plugins.css())
    .end(function (err, string) {
      if (err) throw err;
      fs.writeFileSync(dest + '/' + buildname + '.css', string);
    });

  // copy other files to the build folder
  build.files(tree)
    .use('files', build.plugins.copy())
    .use('fonts', build.plugins.copy())
    .use('images', build.plugins.copy())
    .end(); // callback optional
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone with the same problem: the `.copy()` plugin builds to the `build` folder by default (which I didn't notice, because I was building my css and js to another folder). To have the `.copy()` plugin build to a different folder pass it a different destination like so:

```
var dest = 'name-of-folder-or-complete-path';

// copy other files
build.files(tree, {destination: dest})
  .use('files', build.plugins.copy())
  .use('fonts', build.plugins.copy())
  .use('images', build.plugins.copy())
  .end(); // callback optional
```